# How to write ruby code in (with) cucumber code?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, cucumber

I want to integrate a ruby code in cucumber test:

```
FIX_TOKEN_FOR_TEST_COMPANY = "new_id"
FIX_ID_FOR_TEST_COMPANY    = 184

Given ... do

end

When ... do

end

Then ... do
  c = Company.find( FIX_ID_FOR_TEST_COMPANY );
  c.confirmation_token = FIX_TOKEN_FOR_TEST_COMPANY 
  c.confirmed_at = nil;
  Profile.find_by_email("cucumber@mail.de").destroy;
  c.save(:validate => false)
end
```

Is it right?

Error: Couldn't find Company with ID=184 (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

But if I try to write in in console (terminal) it's work.

Comment: Please provide more relevant code.

Comment: This is all relevant code. I don't understand, why couldn't find Company with ID=184, if I start a test. But if I write it with a keyboard in console - it works. Some tipps?

Comment: Looks like this is related to active record, not watir-webdiver, so I have removed watir-webdriver tag. I have no idea how active record works, so I can not you help.

Comment: It looks like you're using Rails and Devise in addition to plain ruby. Is that correct? If so, I have a theory.